# Insert custom message in the product page just before Reviews section in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, tabs

I am trying to insert a global html message in the Woocommerce products page just before product Reviews.
I got as far as trying:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'custom_notice_for_customisations', 15 );
```

which appears after Reviews.

So it appears we need a global product message in a new tab in the right position?, and I just cannot figure that out.

Any help would be appreciated!

As an added complexity, we've had problems with customers not realizing to click on tabs to view extra information and have removed the tabs view with:

```
/* take prod info etc out of tabs */
#content div.product .woocommerce-tabs .panel {
display: block !important;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}
div.product .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: If you want to add text before the reviews, then the `woocommerce_after_single_product_summary` hook will do, right? _"...So it appears we need a global product message in a new tab in the right position?, and I just cannot figure that out...."_ 
is your question now about adding a new tab? Add text in a existing or custom tab or add text before the tabs?

Comment: Thanks for the help, we are trying to put the product global message between Additional Information and Reviews. After trying `woocommerce_after_single_product_summary` it seems that Additional Information and Reviews are tabs, so we need a new, positioned tab ?

Comment: We can figure out how to make a new tab and display it in the right place, but not how to make its content global